# return df with lowest performers per col or row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to generate a df with the lowest n scores per unit by element. A simplified version would look like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Unit':[''A', 'B', C'], 'leader':['John', 'Jane', 'Joe'],element 1':[1.0, 0.97, 0.65], 'element 2':[0.55, 0.67, 1.0], 'element 3':[0.32, 0.87, 0.66 }, index=['Unit')
```

This results in:

```
       leader  element 1 element 2 element 3
A        John       1.0       0.55     0.32
B        Jane      0.97       0.67     0.87
C         Joe      0.65        1.0     0.66
```

I'm trying to return the top two worst performing elements by score and element tile per unit. The output should look like this:

```
       leader Worst performing element Worst performing score Second worst element Second worse score
Unit 1   John                element 3                  0.32             element 2               0.55
Unit 2   Jane                element 2                  0.67             element 3               0.87
Unit 3    Joe                element 1                  0.65             element 3               0.67
```

I've tried a pivot_table and then looping for the .min() value by row (ex 1), but I can't get the second worse value then. .nsmallest isn't cooperating by row either.

ex1:

```
scorecard = pd.DataFrame()
elements = ['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3']

for row in data:
    scorecard['Unit'] = data['Unit']
    scorecard['leader'] = data['leader']
    scorecard['Lowest Element Compliance'] = april[elements].min(axis=1)
    scorecard['Lowest Performing Element'] = april[elements].idxmin(axis=1)
    unit_sorted = april[elements]

scorecard
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but you're missing some important concepts in `pandas`.

> Keep in mind that looping over a `pandas.DataFrame()` directly will iterate over the dataframe's columns. For example, `for col in pandas.DataFrame()` is the same as `for col in pandas.DataFrame().columns`.

In order to solve your problem, you should've used `pandas.DataFrame().iterrows()` which iterates over the dataframe's column followed by a `.sort_values()` on the rows containing your elements. The solution to your problem will be like this:

```
scorecard = pd.DataFrame()
elements = ['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3']
columns = ['leader', 'Worst performing element', 'Worst performing score', 'Second worst element', 'Second worst score']

for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    # scores sorted in ascending order
    scores = row[elements].sort_values()
    # grab leader value
    leader = row['leader']
    # add values to scorecard
    scorecard.loc[idx, columns] = [leader, scores.index[0], scores.values[0], scores.index[1], scores.values[1]]
    
scorecard
```

Output:

```
        leader  Worst performing element    Worst performing score  Second worst element    Second worst score
Unit 1    John                 element 3                      0.32             element 2                  0.55
Unit 2    Jane                 element 2                      0.67             element 3                  0.87
Unit 3     Joe                 element 1                      0.65             element 3                  0.66
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I am working with it, but getting the error: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['Unit', 'NM', 'Worst performing element', 'Worst performing score',\n       'Second worst element', 'Second worst score'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]`"

Comment: Fixed this by declaring the df scorecard with columns I wanted